# Why is my _document.tsx file not being recognized by my NextJS application?

Tags: typescript, next.js

Can anyone help me understand why my `_document.tsx` won't load in my nextJS app?

### What I've Tried

I'm following documentation with NextJS for creating [_document.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/custom-document). However, for the life of me I can't get my NextJS app to detect the page. I've also tried a similar attempt using `_app.js`. I should note, we use TS so the files are `.tsx` etc.

Here's my default folder structure -- we actually didn't have a root `/pages` folder at all, per the documentation suggests. Everything in our application lives in `/src` and `/src/app`.

[image: folder-structure]

You can see the from the folder structure I tried to:

- place in `projectName/src/pages/_document.tsx`
- also tried in `projectName/pages/_document.tsx`
- also tried in `projectName/src/app/pages/_document.tsx`
- also tried just putting `_document.tsx` in both `projectName/src` root, and `projectName/src/app` root.

Can't seem to get it picked up anywhere: *For the life of me, my `_document.tsx` won't load.*

Here's my `_document.tsx` file, with the script that I simply want to load into  of the application.

Right now I have a work around, but I have a feeling my team is going to call me out and ask me to use `_document.tsx`. But I'm unable to get my NextJS app to find it (and never see script or the console line print `this is document talking`).

***Can anyone help me understand why I'm unable to get my `_document.tsx` to load, and what I'm doing wrong?***

```js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import Script from 'next/script';

class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    console.log("this is document talking");
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <Script>
            {`window.heap=window.heap||[],heap.load=function(e,t){window.heap.appid=e,window.heap.config=t=t||{};var r=document.createElement("script");r.type="text/javascript",r.async=!0,r.src="https://cdn.heapanalytics.com/js/heap-"+e+".js";var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(r,a);for(var n=function(e){return function(){heap.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}},p=["addEventProperties","addUserProperties","clearEventProperties","identify","resetIdentity","removeEventProperty","setEventProperties","track","unsetEventProperty"],o=0;o<p.length;o++)heap[p[o]]=n(p[o])};
  heap.load("123456789");`}
          </Script>
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `app/layout.tsx` takes preference over `pages/_document.tsx` as both are present to render pages in the application. The `pages/_document.tsx` will render the pages present in the pages folder so if you include a page inside the pages dir, the script present in `pages/_document.tsx` will load. If you want to include a script that loads for all the documents present in app and pages, you have to include the same Script in `app/layout.tsx` and `pages/_document.tsx`

Here is an example

```
// app/layout.tsx
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
      <Script>{`console.log("layout")`}</Script>
    </html>
  );
}

export default Page;

// pages/document.tsx
class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    console.log("this is document talking");
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <Script strategy="afterInteractive">{`console.log("pages")`}</Script>
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

// pages/page/1.jsx
import React from "react";
const Page = () => {
  return <div>Page</div>;
};
```

So now when you visit http://localhost:3000/page/1,
[image: browser console on http://localhost:3000/page/1]
[image: server console on http://localhost:3000/page/1]

and when you visit http://localhost:3000/,
[image: browser console on http://localhost:3000/]

Comment: I will give this a try! Do you have any resources to learn more about the loading script? This is super helpful. Will check out my code when I get to work ;P and give it a try!

Comment: Hmm, note: when I add in the class definition that extends `Document`, I get this error :( -- `Server Error - Error: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null. This might be caused by a React Class Component being rendered in a Server Component, React Class Components only works in Client Components. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/class-component-in-server-component`

Comment: There's no way to create a `_document.tsx` or `_app.tsx` and have it be detected by Next? Seems like these need to be modularized, per intended usage?

Comment: Server Error - Error: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null might be caused due to improper imports...make sure to import everything like u did before in _document.tsx

import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import Script from 'next/script';

Comment: about " _document.tsx or _app.tsx and have it be detected by Next", I would suggest that you use a single router. either pages or app. App router is preferred because it has some latest features that pages router doesn't. I don't know your exact use case, but if _document.tsx is mandatory, get rid of the app router and Next will detect _document.tsx for every page